# How to make the file to which screenshots are saved different after each save

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a program in which there is a function that takes screenshots. The code does exactly as it is supposed to, but each time a new screenshot is taken, the previous screenshot is overwritten. I was wondering if there is a way to make the file name different each time a new screenshot is taken. My code to take the screenshot is below.

```
screenshot.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        try {
            BufferedImage screenImage = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
            ImageIO.write(screenImage, "png", new File("screenshots/screenshot.png"));
        } catch (HeadlessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have any number of options...

### You Could

Maintain a counter and each time `actionPerformed` is called, increment the counter and use it as part of the file name for the screen shot...

```
..., new File("screenshots/screenshot" + counter + ".png"));
```

### You Could

List all the files with a matching file name and use that to determine the counter value...

```
File[] files = new File("screenshots").listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File pathname) {
        return pathname.getName().startsWith("screenshot");
    }
});
int counter = files.length + 1;
```

This, of course, does not preclude the possibility that a file will exist with the same count...

### You Could

List the files in the `snapshots` directory, sort them by their numerical index, extract the last one, extract it's counter value and increment it.

This, of course, doesn't preclude the possibility of a numerical overflow...but if you have that many images in your directory, I'd be worried...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe append the data/time as part of the filename.

Or keep a variable that you can use as a sequential counter and use the counter as part of the file name.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to append a variable to the filename. Have a variable declared in the class, and increment it each time you take a screenshot.

```
public class MyClass {
    int screenshotNumber = 0;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        try {
            BufferedImage screenImage = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
            ImageIO.write(screenImage, "png", new File("screenshots/screenshot_" + screenshotNumber++ + ".png"));     
        } catch (HeadlessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you end up with screenshot_0.png, screenshot_1.png, etc.